# Node 18.04.0 - Cannot find module node:test

Tags: node.js, api, testing, automation, response

I am trying to use [node:test](https://nodejs.org/api/test.html) runner library and need to update a nonstable version of node.js 18.04 +

And this is the error that I have got

```
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:949
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/project_name/out/test'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:946:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:787:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: **'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'**,
  requireStack: []
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Update to the latest @types/node if you are using typescript.

```
yarn add -D @types/node
```

If you are using JS in node@18, it should automatically work

```
const test = require('node:test');
```